# Reloading an AS400 S20 with the SAVSYS from an AS400 720

Tags: ibm-midrange

I have an AS400 S20(V4R3M0) that lost 2 disk drives last week and my SAVSYS tape has a media error.
Can I reload the SAVSYS from an AS400 720(V4R5M0) to the S20?
I don't have software subscription on either machine.

Comment: What configuration were the disks in ? Can you dump the tape to HD on the 270 ?

Answer (score 3):

You will **not** be able to do a sysrestore due to the system license keys being different. Your Processor class may also be different which would also result in a license error.